# How to scale content hub images?

Tags: content-hub, dam

We have the option to Scale the images by floating point number (sc=.25 = 25%) in Sitecore XP media library.

Now we have integrated the Sitecore DAM images and want to apply scaling by floating point number.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Transformations to configure your preset renditions and then apply them dynamically to provide users with renditions in different dimensions without the need to regenerate the public link.

So, you can create a new Transformation for your cropping and resizing purpose in the *`Manage -> Transformations`* section, say call it *`"25Resizing"`* and set all the settings in: *`Name`*, *`Crop`*, *`Width`*, *`Height`* and *`Quality`*.
Then in order to apply a transformation to an asset you simply need to append the transformation name to the URL of the public link as a query parameter named `t`. For example, in our case a transformation is called *"25Resizing"* and the value *`&t=25Resizing`* should be applied to the public link URL.

More information about Transformations can be found [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/34/content-hub/manage--transformations.html).

Comment: Thanks Kate. I heard we don't have option to scale based on percentage.